# How to store data type of each of the columns in a dataframe into a new column of a new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's use German credit card data.

```
url <- 'https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat857/sites/onlinecourses.science.psu.edu.stat857/files/german_credit.csv'
credit <- read.csv(url, header = TRUE, sep = ',')
```

I just did one thing: store the names of the columns in a new dataframe:

```
CreditNames <- as.data.frame(names(credit))
View(CreditNames)
```

How can I store the datatype using `typeof(credit)` into a new column?

Something I am trying:

```
for (i in 1:length(GermanCreditCardData)) {
CreditNames[i] <- as.data.frame(names(credit)[i])
}
```

But this is throwing an error.

Comment: No need to use a `for` loop in this situation. Probably easiest with `sapply`. `myTypes <- data.frame(types=sapply(credit, typeof))`. Just run `sapply(credit, typeof)` to see the vector output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you completely then you can use the following:
Using sapply to loopover across all the variables. Check for ?sapply on R terminal.
Not sure why do you want to do it, there is `str` command which can tell you the structure of data, you can also look for **`glimpse`** in `dplyr` package.
`?str` and `?glimpse` for more help. **Thanks to "Imo" for the suggested update.**

```
url <- 'https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat857/sites/onlinecourses.science.psu.edu.stat857/files/german_credit.csv'
credit <- read.csv(url, header = TRUE, sep = ',',stringsAsFactors = F)
dat <- data.frame(type = sapply(credit,typeof))
dat$varname <- rownames(dat)
rownames(dat)  <- NULL
dat <- dat[,c(2,1)]
dat

> dat
                             varname    type
1                      Creditability integer
2                    Account.Balance integer
3         Duration.of.Credit..month. integer
4  Payment.Status.of.Previous.Credit integer
5                            Purpose integer
6                      Credit.Amount integer
7               Value.Savings.Stocks integer
8       Length.of.current.employment integer
9                Instalment.per.cent integer
10              Sex...Marital.Status integer
11                        Guarantors integer
12       Duration.in.Current.address integer
13     Most.valuable.available.asset integer
14                       Age..years. integer
15                Concurrent.Credits integer
16                 Type.of.apartment integer
17        No.of.Credits.at.this.Bank integer
18                        Occupation integer
19                  No.of.dependents integer
20                         Telephone integer
21                    Foreign.Worker integer
```